# How exactly works the assert() method in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, junit4

I have this doubt about JUnit logic.

I have implemented this simple method:

```
@Test
public void testBasic() {
    System.out.println("testBasic() START");

    assert(true);

    System.out.println("testBasic() END");

}
```

And, as expected, it is green because the **assert()** condition is setted to **true**.

Then I change it using:

```
assert(false);
```

And running the test it is green again also if the condition is false.

Reading the documentation I know that I also have the **assertTrue()** to test if a condition is true or false so I can use it.

But then: what is the exact purpose of the simple **assert()** method? When have I to use it and how is used?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039079/unit-test-assert-not-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966347/assert-vs-junit-assertions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` is a Java keyword which refers to Java `assertions` and not a reference to `assertTrue/False/Equals...()` methods from JUnit.
Here is doc for assertions : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

To perform JUnit assertions, import the suitable class : org.junit.Assert
and do :

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class YourTestClass{
  @Test
  public void testBasic() {
    System.out.println("testBasic() START");

    Assert.assertTrue(true); // pass
    Assert.assertFalse(true); // fail

    System.out.println("testBasic() END");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Java assertions there, not JUnit's.

Java assertions are disabled by default. You need to enable them using `-ea` commandline option:

```
java -ea MyClass
```

Comment: mmm what do you mean? Can you explain it better?

Comment: Unless you explicitly turn them on, the runtime will ignore the assertion (and not even evaluate the expression inside). Source: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/assertions-139853.html

Comment: Ah, I see the reason of your confusion now. See davidxxx's post. You're using Java assertions while you think you're using JUnit's assertions.